# Python,convert an array string into an array

Tags: python

I have this string

```
'["el1", "el2", "el3"]'
```

and *it is a string, not an array*, and all of 3 elements can change casually, but the elements are always 3.
I want to create a variable for all the 3 elements, like

```
var1 = "el1"
var2 = "el2"
var3 = "el3"
```

A possible solution is converting this string into an array.. but i don't know how i can do it.
Another solution is splicing the string but as always i don't know how i can do it.
anyone can help?

Comment: just to mention that regex is also a possible solution. the pattern is (?<=\")\w*(?=\"), and we can use re.findall(...)

Answer (score -1):

It seems like your string is in the JSON format. You can make a list from it like this:

```py
import json

string = '["el1", "el2", "el3"]'
list_from_string = json.loads(string)

print(list_from_string) # outputs ['el1', 'el2', 'el3']
```

It could also be done using the `eval` function as stated in the other answer. I advise against that, because `eval` can be very dangerous if you are getting the string as an input from the user.

You probably really don't want to create a variable for every item of your array input. If you create a list from it, you can then iter over it. You could for example use a `for` loop like this to print every item from your input array:

```py
for i in list_from_string:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
el1
el2
el3
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `ast.literal_eval` is the correct approach for this over using `eval` as it's unsafe:

```
from ast import literal_eval

s = '["el1", "el2", "el3"]'
 
var1, var2, var3 = literal_eval(s)
```

---

```
>>> var1
el1
>>> var2
el2
>>> var3
el3
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this out:

```py
import ast

str = '["el1", "el2", "el3"]'
list_of_values = ast.literal_eval(str)

val1 = list_of_values[0]
val2 = list_of_values[1]
val3 = list_of_values[2]
print(val1)
print(val2)
print(val3)
```

output:

```bash
el1
el2
el3
```